# Entity Framework - force commit without transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have a loop that looks a bit like this:

```
CountsToReport = rep.Counts_Get().Where(x => x.Status == "Completed");

foreach (var count in CountsToReport.ToList())
{
    //do some stuff
    //send an email

    count.Status = "Reported";
    rep.SaveChanges();
}
```

Where "rep" is a repository wrapper around an EF context.

When this runs, the unfortunate email recipient gets deluged with spam because the SaveChanges call doesn't actually commit the changes - so the loop keep getting the same counts, emailing them, and marking them as "Reported" but doesn't actually save the change.

If you stop the loop, and re-start the code, the change saves successfully. You can confirm this scenario by stepping through the code: the EF object in C# changes its Status, but the underlying data in SQL doesn't change.

I'm presuming this is because SaveChanges doesn't actually *commit* the transaction - it just marks the data as having changed ready for the end of the transaction. But we're not using transactions anywhere else in the DB, and it'd be a bit of a pain to change the repository for this one use case.

Is there any other way I can force EF to commit this change and escape my endless loop of doom? Or am I mistaken about the cause?

EDIT: Putting this in the repository and calling it instead of SaveChanges his fixes it:

```
public void SaveWithTransaction()
{
    using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

But it seems ugly. Still interested to know if there's another way round.

EDIT: This is deceptive. It looks like it's just the old add/modified problem again. Marking the object as modified seems to help.

Comment: Can you use a SQL profiler to check which (if any) statements are executed on the database?

Comment: Do you have a loop outside the code you pasted?

Comment: And you are already trying solutions without knowing what the exact problem is. **First** try to find out what the problem is, **then** find a solution to fix it.

Comment: Check if Distributed Transaction Coordinator service (MS DTC) is running.

Comment: @thsorens No, it's being called intermittently from a Timer. But the effect is just the same.

Comment: @Maarten I think it's sometimes okay to make intuitive leaps, especially if they're educated ones.

Comment: @Andrew I think it is. The SQL command "begin distributed transaction" executes successfully, which I believe indicates it's running and is configured correctly?

Comment: yes, sounds to be ok. Another thing you may want to play with is another `SaveChanges` method that take `SaveOptions` parameter. Try executing it like this: `dataContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);` or use `SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave`

Comment: @Maarten Running a trace suggests that no update command is being called - nothing relevant from EF appears in the trace when you step over the code in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible that entities in your CountsToReport are detached from context. 
Thus not only ChangeTracker doesn't see any sort of change done over Count, it doesn't know anything about the entity at all.

To have the issue fixed:

- iterate through collection of CountsToReport
- attach each entity back to context, something like `db.Counts.Attach(count)`
- modify the count.Status and call db.SaveChanges();

like this:

```
foreach (var count in CountsToReport.ToList())
{
    //do some stuff
    //send an email
    rep.Counts.Attach(count);
    count.Status = "Reported";
    rep.SaveChanges();
}
```

Have a look at the following link for more information about entity states and how to deal with them:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx